# Grails plugin package custom files to ZIP

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm developing a plugin in Grails 2.3.8 and I need to install custom asset to the target application. I want to copy it using `_Install.groovy` script after the plugin is installed.

From the *Burt Beckwith's Programming Grails* book, these files and file patterns are by default included when packaging a plugin.

- application.properties
- dependencies.groovy
- *GrailsPlugin.groovy
- LICENSE
- LICENSE.txt
- plugin.xml
- docs/api/**
- docs/gapi/**
- grails-app/**
- lib/**
- scripts/**
- src/**
- web-app/**

I'm putting my asset in `grails-app/assets` folder and I expect it to appear in plugin folder under the same path after running `package-plugin` command. **But it's not there.**

Answer (score 0):

There must be something in your project that is getting in the way because by default this will work...

```
grails create-plugin gadget && cd gadget && mkdir grails-app/assets && echo "something" > grails-app/assets/stuff.txt && grails package-plugin && unzip -l grails-gadget-0.1.zip |grep stuff
```